# Spring @Value annotation does not work when a advice is applied

Tags: java, spring

@Value annotation does not inject Spel result into property when some aspects are available to execute.
It works perfectly when I comment out advice from DbAspect or I try to access properties using getters.

Code is:

Application.java:

```
package com.spring.demo;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        Dummy dummy = ctx.getBean(Dummy.class);

        System.out.println(dummy.integer);
        System.out.println(dummy.name);
        System.out.println(dummy.map);
        System.out.println(dummy.list);
    }
}
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.demo"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
</beans>
```

DbAspect.java:

```
package com.spring.demo;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class DbAspect {

    @Before("execution(void *.*(..))")
    void beforeAdvice() {
        System.out.println("=======================args advice");
    }
}
```

Dummy.java

```
package com.spring.demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Dummy {

    @Value("#{2*2}")
    public Integer integer;

    @Value("#{'SpEL'}")
    public String name;

    @Value("#{{a:2,b:3,c:3}}")
    Map map;

    @Value("#{{1,2,3,4,5}}")
    List list;

}
```

Is it spring convention to access properties using getters with AOP duo to  proxies?

Comment: Yes. Proxies can't proxy fields. There's a ton of good reasons not to use public fields. This is one of them. It's not a Spring convention to void fields. It's an OO convention: encapsulation.

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal You should read [JavaBeans spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).